# add icon with UI-grid celltemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Here is the tutorial link for angular ui-grid editable feature.
[UI-Grid Editable Link](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable)

Every row is editable (not header). But I want to add icon to let the user know that this row or cell is editable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular ui-grid custom header html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377210/angular-ui-grid-custom-header-html)

Comment: As per the requirements it should be on rows not on header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display using `cellTemplate`.

```
 cellTemplate: '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>'
```

Here is an working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MaSuKSnk7HvdjK4DERlR?p=preview) where the gender icon is placed.

You can replace the icon as per your requirement. Hope this helps.

Comment: {enableGridMenu: true, exporterMenuPdf: false, 
   cellTemplate:'<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>'

Comment: can you create a plunkr for your issue?

Comment: it works for me partially,  I am able to show only icon but not able to show the values which I am getting from web-services